# LM22673 diode selection

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, buck, bms

[image]

I'm fairly new to electronics, and in my project I'm using LM22673 as Buck Converter in this Diode selection parts this is given which is confusing for me.

as

1. Ultra-fast diodes can switch very fast, so what's the issue with that? How it will damage the IC?
2. Also, why choose a diode with reverse breakdown rating of max Vin. It's on Output side right, so why does it matter?

Comment: The diode is "inside" (on the switching node), the output is "after" the inductor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reverse recovery**

There are several good posts on this forum that describe this phenomenon.
[What is the reverse recovery time in a diode?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/what-is-the-reverse-recovery-time-in-a-diode). What they are stating in the datasheet is that the Schottky diode has even better reverse recovery characterstics than an ultra fast one.

**Reverse breakdown voltage**

The output voltage of an ideal buck converter is between 0V and Vin. Therefore the highest possible voltage the diode can experience is Vin. However, considering tolerances, voltage ripple/spikes etc it is a good idea to add some safety margin.